# Excel VBA macro to pull name of file to body of automatic email

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that sends an email to management whenever someone opens the file.  In the body of the email it includes their User ID but I would also like to have it display the name of the file that was opened. Below is my code that auto composes the email:

```
mItem.Subject = "RLS Report Opened"
mItem.Body = "This is an automated message to inform you that " & _
             Environ("username") & " has downloaded and is using the file."
```

I would like the filename to be inserted "...has downloaded and is using the file [filename here]."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ActiveWorkbook.FullName`, which will return the full file path including the name, or use `ActiveWorkbook.Name`, which will return just the file name.